# Validation not working for dynamically added rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery. I wrote validation for the input fields. And dynamically generating the input fields when click add row. I gave the same `id` value to all input fields. But the new generated rows was not validating when i click the button.

Where i did mistake. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mobile").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});


$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function () {

    var a = $("#name").val();
    var b = $("#country").val();
    var c = $("#mail_id").val();
    var d = $("#mobile").val();


    if (a == "") {
        $("#name").addClass("error");
    }
    else {
        $("#name").removeClass("error");
    }

    if (b == "") {
        $("#country").addClass("error");
    }
    else {
        $("#country").removeClass("error");
    }

    if (c == "" ) {
        $("#mail_id").addClass("error");
    }
    else {
        $("#mail_id").removeClass("error");
    }

    if (d == "") {
        $("#mobile").addClass("error");
    }
    else {
        $("#mobile").removeClass("error");
    }

    var i = 1;
    if (a == '' || b == '' || c == '' || d == '') {
        i = 1;
    }
    else {
        $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='checkbo" + i + "' type='checkbox' placeholder='' class='check'  /></td><td><input name='name" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md' id='name'/> </td><td><select name='country" + i + "' class='form-control' id='country'><option value=''>select an option</option><option value='afghan'>Afghanistan</option><option value='albania'>Albania</option></select></td><td><input  name='mail" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'  id='mail_id'></td><td><input  name='mobile" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md' id='mobile'></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
        i++;
    }

    $("#delete_row").click(function () {
        if (i > 1) {
            $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.error{
    border: 1px solid red;
    transition: border-color .25s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                        <thead>
                            <tr >
                                <th>

                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Name
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Address
                                </th>
                                <th class="text-center">
                                    Mobile
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id='addr0'>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="check_0">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control name" id="name" required>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control"> 
                                        <option value="">select an option</option>
                                        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='mail0' class="form-control" id="mail_id" required>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='mobile0' placeholder='Mobile' class="form-control" id="mobile" required>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id='addr1'></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should never share ids. ID should be unique for a website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like I commented, you should **never** use same ids for fields. IDs should be unique for fields.

From [XHTML 1.0 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10),

> In XML, fragment identifiers are of type ID, and there can only be a
>   single attribute of type ID per element. Therefore, in XHTML 1.0 the
>   id attribute is defined to be of type ID. In order to ensure that
>   XHTML 1.0 documents are well-structured XML documents, XHTML 1.0
>   documents MUST use the id attribute when defining fragment identifiers
>   on the elements listed above. See the HTML Compatibility Guidelines
>   for information on ensuring such anchors are backward compatible when
>   serving XHTML documents as media type text/html.

I have refactored your code. Here is the working demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/4onh3nrx/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th>

                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Address
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Mobile
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Action
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check_0">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control name" id="name" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control country"> 
                                <option value="">select an option</option>
                                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name='mail0' class="form-control mail_id" id="mail_id" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name='mobile0' placeholder='Mobile' class="form-control mobile" id="mobile" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning add-row">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mobile").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.add-row', function(){
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var field = [
            '.name', '.country', '.mail_id', '.mobile'
        ];
        console.log(tr);
        var flag = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            var ele = $.trim($(tr).find(field[i]).val());
            console.log(ele);
            console.log($(tr).find(field[i]));
            if(!ele.length) {
                flag = true;
                $(tr).find(field[i]).addClass('error');
            } else {
                $(tr).find(field[i]).removeClass('error');
            }
        }

        if (!flag) {
            var html = "<tr><td><input name='checkbo" + i + "' type='checkbox' placeholder='' class='check'  /></td><td><input name='name" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control name input-md'/> </td><td><select name='country" + i + "' class='form-control country'><option value=''>select an option</option><option value='afghan'>Afghanistan</option><option value='albania'>Albania</option></select></td><td><input  name='mail" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='mail_id form-control input-md'></td><td><input  name='mobile" + i + "' type='text' placeholder='Mobile'  class='form-control input-md mobile'></td><td><a href='#' class='btn btn-warning add-row'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i></a><a href='#' class='btn btn-danger delete-row'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></i></a></td></tr>";
            $(html).insertAfter(tr);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ha ha. Glad I could help bro ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should not assign same `id` to inputs, id must be unique.

Assign same class name to all the inputs that you want to validate like:

```js
$().ready(function() {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#btn1').click(function() {
        $('.class1').each(function() {
            $('#div1').hide();
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $('#div1').show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Error</div>
<input class="class1"/>
<input class="class1"/>
<input class="class1"/>
<button id="btn1">Click here</button>
```

This will also work for dynamically added inputs.